# How to achieve this effect where when a user scrolls down the next div takes over the content of above div while not making the content move up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

[Video Showing the effect i want to learn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13tA7IFGI0JKdLMbadQkCm3_Tpyk1f_ZA/view?usp=sharing)

How can i achieve the same effect?

When a user scrolls down the next div takes over the content of above div while not making the content move up but having whiteOut effect instead on the old div and the new div just takes over the content of the old div!

I have minimal experience with CSS and JS but still i did try to achieve it with chatGPT and other tools but it wasn't that helpful...

I also tried GSAP Library and still the results wasn't satisfactory.

what would i be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share any code examples of what you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Another community i reached out to says this can be achieved with Framer Motion Library for react, but as i am in learning phase i was wondering if same can be done with raw js and css